# "I have sent it to X too" vs. "I have sent it to X also"

Tags: word-choice, difference, adverbs, too-also

- I have sent this e-mail to Aman also.
- I have sent this e-mail to Aman too.

Which one is correct? What is the exact difference between the two? Please explain.

Comment: I'm not used to *also* at the end of a long sentence. I would say that *too*, in this case, is the more likely alternative for native speakers. (I'm still wondering that native speakers might utter something else entirely to express this idea. Back to the case of *also* at the end of the mentioned sentence. If they wanted to say *also*, they would tag it along with *sent*. If they wanted to add that she sent it "also", I think it would come out as *too* or *as well* in spontaneous speech.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think you are right and your comment deserves being promoted to an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context you are asking about, the two words are very synonymous, so there is no "exact difference" between the two.

When I am choosing one over the other, my choice is often based on style, and how they sound. For example, in this sentence, I would use *also*, simply because it sounds better (who wants to say "two-too"?):

> When I asked if they wanted a slice of bread, Jim asked for two, and Jane asked for two, too.
>   When I asked if they wanted a slice of bread, Jim asked for two, and Jane asked for two, also.

Moreover, this is a generality, but I think *also* usually sounds better in technical writing; it seems slightly more formal:

> The graph shows that the function *f*(x) is continuous, and *g*(x) is continuous, also.

At the beginning of a sentence, *also* just about always the better word:

> Also, I sent this email to Aman yesterday.

However, at the end of a sentence, when you're indicating "as well", there's really not much difference in which one you use (although a comma is generally used before *too* in this context):

> I have sent this e-mail to Aman also.
>   I have sent this e-mail to Aman, too.

Answer (score 1):

When used like you have here to mean *as well,* or *in addition to,* they are interchangeable.